# Looper.prepare error on Timer

Tags: java, android

Suppose you have this class managing a timer. It is just a test.

```
package it.rockopera.scsremote;
import android.content.Context;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CueTimer extends Thread{
    private Context context;
    private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    private Timer timer;
    int elapsed = 0 ;

    public CueTimer(Context c){
        context= c;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                elapsed+=1000;
                System.out.println("elapsed: " + String.valueOf(elapsed));                  
            }
        },0,1000); //Update text every second
    }
}
```

I would like to call this method from another class in this way:

```
CueTimer cuetimer = new CueTimer(context);
cuetimer.start()
```

here's the error:

> Process: it.rockopera.scsremote, PID: 7562
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:789)
>                                                                             at it.rockopera.scsremote.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:47)
>                                                                             at it.rockopera.scsremote.CueTimer.(CueTimer.java:32)
>                                                                             at it.rockopera.scsremote.Client$Read_SCS_MSGs.run(Client.java:477)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

I try to look for this error but I can't find anything similar.
Thanks !!

Comment: can you give the full class code of CueTimer and also the class from where you are calling cuetimer.start()?

Comment: `main = new MainActivity();` you are not allowed to create instances of activities yourself. leave that to the system.

Comment: I commented main = new MainActivity(); since it is not used in this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each new thread should call `Looper.prepare()` in case you want to use `Handler`

> Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them;
> to ?create one, call prepare() in the thread that is to run the loop,
> and then loop() to have it process messages until the loop is stopped.

But the issue in your code actually at this line :

```
 private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

There is two problems actually. First - looks like you creating `CueTimer` not on a main thread which causing instantiation of `MainActivity` not on main thread too. Second - never instantiate activities directly. Your activity should be registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` and accessed through `Intent`.

Comment: I commented private MainActivity main = new MainActivity(); since it is not used in CueTimer method.

Comment: Where should I call Looper.prepare() in the proposed code ?

Comment: Your proposed code is not valid due to manual creation of `Activity`. If you eliminate that - you will not need to call `Looper.prepare()`.

Comment: CueTimer activity has no xml layout. If I try to register it in AndroidManifest.xml I obtain error 'has not default constructor ...'

Comment: You need to read about android development. Here is good intro https://developer.android.com/training/index.html. 
As far as I see in your example `CueTimer` is `Thread` not an `Activity`